# Pandas: Convert dataframe columns into dict with col title as dict key and col values as dict values

Tags: python, pandas, dictionary

I have a data frame that looks like:

```
      NAME              ID 
155  ARBITRARY_A    697381   
208  ARBITRARY_B    691820   
265  ARBITRARY_C    691782   
272  ARBITRARY_D    695593
```

I want to convert it into a list of dictionaries that looks like:

```
[{name:ARBITRARY_A, id:697381}, {name:ARBITRARY_B, id:691820},
 {name:ARBITRARY_C, id:691782}, {name:ARBITRARY_D, id:695593}]
```

What is the fastest/optimum way to do this operation?

Comment: `df.to_dict('record')`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As indicated in comments, [`pandas.DataFrame.to_dict()`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.to_dict.html) can be used.  And in your case you need to `orient` as `record`:

**Code:**

```
df.to_dict('record')
```

**Test Code:**

```
df = pd.read_fwf(StringIO(u"""
          NAME              ID
    155  ARBITRARY_A    697381
    208  ARBITRARY_B    691820
    265  ARBITRARY_C    691782
    272  ARBITRARY_D    695593"""),
                 header=1, index_col=0)

print(df)
print(df.to_dict('record'))
```

**Results:**

```
            NAME      ID
155  ARBITRARY_A  697381
208  ARBITRARY_B  691820
265  ARBITRARY_C  691782
272  ARBITRARY_D  695593

[{u'NAME': u'ARBITRARY_A', u'ID': 697381L}, {u'NAME': u'ARBITRARY_B', u'ID': 691820L}, {u'NAME': u'ARBITRARY_C', u'ID': 691782L}, {u'NAME': u'ARBITRARY_D', u'ID': 695593L}]
```

Comment: Great answer!  I particularly like your use of **bold** plus one from me :-)

Comment: Everything tastes better in bold.

Answer (score 6):

You can squeeze a little more performance out of it by doing the comprehensions yourself

```
v = df.values.tolist()
c = df.columns.values.tolist()

[dict(zip(c, x)) for x in v]

[{'ID': 697381L, 'NAME': 'ARBITRARY_A'},
 {'ID': 691820L, 'NAME': 'ARBITRARY_B'},
 {'ID': 691782L, 'NAME': 'ARBITRARY_C'},
 {'ID': 695593L, 'NAME': 'ARBITRARY_D'}]
```

***small given `df`***
[image]

***larger `d1`***
[image]

Comment: Pretty colors, but we need to figure out how to do that in mark up, instead of `png`.  Or maybe copy and paste from iPython to SO markup should be a thing?

Comment: You may have just motivated me to come up with something better :-)

Comment: @piRSquared I got another one for you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43504945/pandas-select-rows-based-on-multiple-object-values-inside-a-column :)

Answer (score 2):

Try:

```
df.to_dict()
```

if this does not produce the intended result try to transpose the DataFrame:

```
df.T.to_dict()
```